# How to target specific options pages in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to remove screen options from a specific page and I've got something that removes screen options from all pages so I just need to check for "when page == {x}"  How do I check what page I'm on in wordpress though?

```
function remove_screen_options(){
    return false;
}
add_filter('screen_options_show_screen', 'remove_screen_options');
```

Thought it would be as easy as:

```
    function remove_screen_options(){
  global $pagename;
  if( $pagename == "admin_faucet_settings") {
    return false;
  }
}
add_filter('screen_options_show_screen', 'remove_screen_options');
```

But that is not working - seems to fire all the time too which is strange and off...any ideas?

Comment: In a fact plugin settings page is not a wordpress page so you cannot use the same functions for identifying the page. Maybe this will help you: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7278/how-can-you-check-if-you-are-in-a-particular-page-in-the-wp-admin-section-for-e

Comment: yes thank you! did you search for this or knew about it beforehand?

Comment: Well I used it in development before but it was faster to search here rather than recalling in which project I used it and copying a code from there to show you :)

Comment: Take my last edit in there and use that in a separate answer I'll mark yours as solved

Comment: Thanks. I think you could change your title to something like "how to target specific options page on WordPress" to make it clearer for other people who need to solve similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you need to target any particular page of wordpress admin area, such as plugin page then you can use admin enqueue script hook like this:

```
function my_admin_enqueue($hook_suffix) {
    if($hook_suffix == 'faucet_admin_settings') {
      // your code that should be executed if we are on the right page.
    }
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_enqueue');
```

Reference: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7278/how-can-you-check-if-you-are-in-a-particular-page-in-the-wp-admin-section-for-e